# PC: Multiple OS - Fedora goes first

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, fedora

Ok, I know the title doesn't make any sense, but it was hard.

Anyways, I have a problem with multiple oses on my pc. This is what I got:

- Windows 7
- Fedora 15
- Ubuntu 11.04

The problem is that when I first start my pc it shows a Fedora only menu which also says something like: 'Press any key to blablabla...'. If I just leave it there for 3 seconds it boots Fedora. When I press a key on my keyboard, it displays a menu with all my oses.

How can I throw the Fedora only menu in the ocean? I just want the menu with all my oses.

Oh, and do you say oses? I ain't that good in english he he.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with customizing your grub config and reinstalling grub2(not sure if the version issue in fedora...like if they're using grub or grub2).  I know ubuntu uses grub2 for some time now.

Comment: Is there a gui for that or do I have to do some super terminal hacking?

Comment: a gui exists but I've always done it from the terminal.  if it deals with boot or kernel i just don't trust a gui for some reason.  maybe I'm paranoid...

Comment: @aking1012 - You're paranoid. :)

Comment: @Shinrai - thx for clearing that up :)

Comment: Ok, but how do I do it then? :)

Comment: if you have a specific question on a particular part of it post in the comments...the meat of the procedure is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 although some file locations may vary on redhat based